Replace UNION ALL (ClickHouse)
I've a table where I need to put values from two columns into one column. Values from columns conversions and goal_reaches shoulg go to common column: metric_value. And another column metric_type should have different values. For column conversions it should ends as GoalVisit and for column goal_reaches should ends as Goal.
Simple solution - use UNION ALL. I'm almost okay with it, but later I'll meet problems with scalability. Because for another column I will have to use another UNION ALL. How can I replace it in ClickHouse? In PostgreSQL I could probably use cross join lateral.
View:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW metrika.goal_conversions_report_matched
(
    `counter_id` Nullable(Int64),
    `goal_id` Int64,
    `date_of_visit` Date,
    `utm_campaign` Nullable(String),
    `utm_source` Nullable(String),
    `utm_medium` Nullable(String),
    `utm_content` Nullable(String),
    `utm_term` Nullable(String),
    `original_join_id` String,
    `last_update_time` Nullable(DateTime),
    `metric_value` Nullable(Int64), 
    `counter_name` Nullable(String),
    `owner_login` Nullable(String),
    `counter_status` Nullable(String),
    `metric_type` Nullable(String),
    `metric_key` Nullable(String),
    `metric_name` Nullable(String)
) AS
SELECT
    ufc.counter_id AS counter_id,
    gcrvf.goal_id AS goal_id,
    gcrvf.date_of_visit AS date_of_visit,
    ufc.utm_campaign AS utm_campaign,
    ufc.utm_source AS utm_source,
    ufc.utm_medium AS utm_medium,
    ufc.utm_content AS utm_content,
    ufc.utm_term AS utm_term,
    ufc.original_join_id AS original_join_id,
    max(gcrvf.last_update_time) AS last_update_time,
    sum(gcrvf.conversions) AS metric_value, 
    c.name AS counter_name,
    c.owner_login AS owner_login,
    c.status AS counter_status,
    concat(g.goal_source, 'GoalVisit') AS metric_type, 
    multiIf(g.is_retargeting = 0, 'non-retargeting', g.is_retargeting = 1, 'retargeting', NULL) AS metric_key,
    concat(g.name, ' (', CAST(gcrvf.goal_id, 'String'), ')') AS metric_name
FROM metrika.goal_conversions_report AS gcrvf
INNER JOIN metrika.utm_for_collect AS ufc ON gcrvf.counter_id = ufc.counter_id
LEFT JOIN metrika.counter AS c ON gcrvf.counter_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN metrika.goal AS g ON gcrvf.goal_id = g.id
WHERE ((gcrvf.utm_campaign = ufc.utm_campaign) OR (ufc.utm_campaign IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_source = ufc.utm_source) OR (ufc.utm_source IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_medium = ufc.utm_medium) OR (ufc.utm_medium IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_content = ufc.utm_content) OR (ufc.utm_content IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_term = ufc.utm_term) OR (ufc.utm_term IS NULL))
GROUP BY
    ufc.counter_id, gcrvf.date_of_visit, gcrvf.goal_id, ufc.utm_campaign, ufc.utm_source,
    ufc.utm_medium, ufc.utm_content, ufc.utm_term, ufc.original_join_id, c.name,
    c.owner_login, c.status, metric_type, metric_key, metric_name

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ufc.counter_id AS counter_id,
    gcrvf.goal_id AS goal_id,
    gcrvf.date_of_visit AS date_of_visit,
    ufc.utm_campaign AS utm_campaign,
    ufc.utm_source AS utm_source,
    ufc.utm_medium AS utm_medium,
    ufc.utm_content AS utm_content,
    ufc.utm_term AS utm_term,
    ufc.original_join_id AS original_join_id,
    max(gcrvf.last_update_time) AS last_update_time,
    sum(gcrvf.goal_reaches) AS metric_value, -- Sum of goal_reaches
    c.name AS counter_name,
    c.owner_login AS owner_login,
    c.status AS counter_status,
    concat(g.goal_source, 'Goal') AS metric_type, 
    multiIf(g.is_retargeting = 0, 'non-retargeting', g.is_retargeting = 1, 'retargeting', NULL) AS metric_key,
    concat(g.name, ' (', CAST(gcrvf.goal_id, 'String'), ')') AS metric_name
FROM metrika.goal_conversions_report AS gcrvf
INNER JOIN metrika.utm_for_collect AS ufc ON gcrvf.counter_id = ufc.counter_id
LEFT JOIN metrika.counter AS c ON gcrvf.counter_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN metrika.goal AS g ON gcrvf.goal_id = g.id
WHERE ((gcrvf.utm_campaign = ufc.utm_campaign) OR (ufc.utm_campaign IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_source = ufc.utm_source) OR (ufc.utm_source IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_medium = ufc.utm_medium) OR (ufc.utm_medium IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_content = ufc.utm_content) OR (ufc.utm_content IS NULL)) AND
      ((gcrvf.utm_term = ufc.utm_term) OR (ufc.utm_term IS NULL))
GROUP BY
    ufc.counter_id, gcrvf.date_of_visit, gcrvf.goal_id, ufc.utm_campaign, ufc.utm_source,
    ufc.utm_medium, ufc.utm_content, ufc.utm_term, ufc.original_join_id, c.name,
    c.owner_login, c.status, metric_type, metric_key, metric_name;


Would COALESCE work here? either way, consider CTEs for easier readability
